# Set sidebar DIV equal in height to a sibling content DIV using jQuery--not working for me

Tags: jquery, html

[Here's](http://www.chicgeekbeauty.com/sample-product-apple-ipod-socks/) a page where I'm trying this.

I got my divs to all look the same height with a CSS hack.  Now I'm trying to set the height of the right sidebar so that it is never longer than the main content of the page.

This is the script on the page right now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(".Right2").css({'height':($(".Content").height()+'px')});
</script>
```

It does not work, obviously.  All I want is for .Right2 to me the same height as .Content, and it needs to be determined dynamically.

Can somebody help a girl out?  Thanks!

(Obviously, this isn't my product yet.  I'm still bashing away at layout.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#Trial2").css('height',$("#Trial1").height());
   });
</script>
```

In your code above you are selecting elements with specific class. Since more elements can have the same class then `$(".myClass")` may return an array and not a single object. Use ID's instead as in my example above and you will get rid of future problems!

And of course, you shouldn't forget to run the code after the DOM is ready!

Comment: I'm hacking something my eCommerce company made, and I have no idea why they set their columns to classes rather than IDs.  That "Trial" was me seeing whether the ids they had referenced jack, after searching the css files and finding nothing-and, apparently, they don't.  Honestly, I should delete the Trial1 and Trial2 and make Left2, Right2, and Content into IDs because there can't be more than one a page of any of them.

Comment: They probably had a lack of knowledge of HTML classes and IDs. Good that you have taken over the project and fix all those issues :) Have fun using jQuery, it's awesome! :) If the code above worked for you, please accept it as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, it just needs to be wrapped. I you don't wrap your code in `ready` or `load` then the DOM elements don't exist at your time of code execution. So nothing happens.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
   $(".Right2").css({'height':($(".Content").height()+'px')});
});
</script>
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  I stopped doing web dev 6 years ago and this is my first go at using jQuery.  I searched everywhere for how to make the thing execute, but the examples I found didn't look like anything was missing.  PERFECT!

Comment: @Genevieve - you are welcome. Make sure you tick off that Green check to the left of my answer. An upvote would be good too =).

Answer (score 0):

The div your targeting for height does it have a set or fluid height?

Comment: Fluid.  I wish set!  EVERYTHING is dynamic.